# Understanding uniform convergence and the M-test

Tags: uniform-convergence

Consider $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(1 + x/n)}$$

where $x \in (-1,\infty)$.

At $n = 1$, we have $\frac{1}{1 + x}$, and surely this can be made as close to infinity as we want. Is it then not possible to use Weierstrass' M-test to show uniform convergence?

I'm still trying to get my head around this topic, so I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2(1+x/n)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(x+n)}=\frac{\gamma+\psi(x+1)}{x}\tag{1}$$
where $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)  and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

The regularity of the RHS of $(1)$ over $x>-1$ can be deduced from the regularity of $\Gamma(s)$ over $\text{Re}(s)>0$ or from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, from which:

$$\left|\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(x+n)}\right|\leq \sqrt{\zeta(2)}\sqrt{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}}.\tag{2}$$